# How does play framework unit testing controller methods

Tags: unit-testing, scala, playframework-2.0

According to the documentation, to unit test controllers, I need to make my controllers a trait, then override the methods

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/ScalaTest

However, if I override my methods, i'm effectively not testing my logic. I may not be grasping something, but I don't see how this unit tests my controller's methods?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the example in the link you've provided is that it doesn't really show the benefit of having your controller implementation within a trait. In other words, the same example could've been accomplished without using traits by just testing the controller companion object directly.

The benefit of having your controller logic be within a trait is that it allows you to override dependencies that controller may have with mock implementations/values.

For example, you could define a controller as:

```
trait MyController extends Controller {
   lazy val someService : SomeService = SomeServiceImpl
}
object MyController extends MyController
```

And in your test, you can override the service dependency:

```
val controller = new MyController {
  override lazy val someService = mockService
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the link the controllers in play are scala objects not classes so can't be instantiated like a class. By making it a trait instead you can make a test class which you can instantiate in your test. No need to override the methods though.

To use the example from the link, here we are making a TestController class that has the same behaviour as the ExampleController object. We don't need to override our index method as we inherit the behaviour from the trait.

Main file

```
trait ExampleController {
  this: Controller =>

  def index() = Action {
    Ok("ok")
  }
}

object ExampleController extends Controller with ExampleController
```

Test File

```
object ExampleControllerSpec extends PlaySpecification with Results {

  class TestController() extends Controller with ExampleController

  "Example Page#index" should {
    "should be valid" in {
      val controller = new TestController()
      val result: Future[SimpleResult] = controller.index().apply(FakeRequest())
      val bodyText: String = contentAsString(result)
      bodyText must be equalTo "ok"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple example of how you can check if some url is available

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.runner._
import org.junit.runner._

import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._

/**
 * Set of tests which are just hitting urls and check
 * if response code 200 returned
 */
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class ActionsSanityCheck extends Specification {

  def checkIfUrlAccessible(url: String): Unit = {
    val appRoute = route(FakeRequest(GET, url)).get

    status(appRoute) must equalTo(OK)
    contentType(appRoute) must beSome.which(_ == "text/html")
  }

  "Application" should {

    "send 404 on a bad request" in new WithApplication {
      route(FakeRequest(GET, "/nowhere")) must beNone
    }

    "render the index page" in new WithApplication {checkIfUrlAccessible("/")}
    "render team page" in new WithApplication {checkIfUrlAccessible("/team")}
  }
}
```